# Wrong value retrieved for property stored on DFM in a custom component

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, custom-component

Delphi XE2

I have the followind custom component:

```
  TNaharWebDBEdit = class(TUniDBEdit)
  private
    FThemeColor : TNaharPalleteColor;
    FThemeController: TNaharThemeController;
    procedure   OnObserver(Sender: TObject; AParam, AValue: Variant);
    procedure   UpdateColor;
    procedure   SetColor(const Value: TNaharPalleteColor);
    function    GetThemeManager: TNaharThemeManager;
  protected
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor  Destroy; override;
  published
    property    ThemeColor: TNaharPalleteColor read FThemeColor write SetColor default npcWhite;
    property    ThemeManager: TNaharThemeManager read GetThemeManager;
  end;
```

the SetColor code is:

```
procedure TNaharWebDBEdit.SetColor(const Value: TNaharPalleteColor);
begin
  FThemeColor := Value;

  UpdateColor;
end;
```

where UpdateColor just retrive the current assigned color for the theme and set is on Self.Color.

Everything works fine. The property ThemeColor shows up on the property view and I can change it to other values. However right after I save the form and open back again it is back to the original value, and not even the default one.

I made 12 components like this, and all similiar code. Only on the Panel (from TuniPanel) is working correctly, the property keeps the value assigned during the design and retrieve it correctly on runtime.

Somewhow the value is not saved or not property restored. How to catch that?

EDIT:

```
  TNaharPalleteColor = (npcMainColor, npcColorA, npcColorB, npcColorC, npcColorD, npcWhite, npcBlack, npcUnknown, npcNone);
```

I have changed the value of ThemeColor to npcWhite and saved. I opened the DFM on Notepad++ and found it was NOT SAVED

I have added the STORED TRUE on the property and it did not make any difference, still not storing it there.

However if I close the form and open it again it shows the ThemeColor as npcMainColor (0) instead of the default that is npcWhite

EDIT:
I have opened other forms that are using this component and could see that previously the property was getting saved. When opened and saved back again it gets removed from the DFM. The only one that remains working is the descendant from TuniPanel, that is a TPanel. But it has exacly the same code, it is all copy and paste.

I have removed this line from the class:

```
    FThemeController: TNaharThemeController;
```

and the component is now saving correctly the FThemeColor on the DFM, working as expected. Why?

Comment: How is defined `TNaharPalleteColor` type ?

Comment: "Somewhow the value is not saved or not property restored" - no "or". You should determine what exactly happens there. That would half the potential area of errors. So after you save the form - open DFM file in Notepad or in sometext viewer in Total Commander, Unreal Commander etc. In some passive text viewer that would not run the actual component code. And see whether the proper color was saved or not.

Comment: TUniPanel is somethign from that mysterious TUniGUI lib ? i don;t know if we can assume anythign about how UniGUI workgin. t is somethign unusual with closed sources

Comment: @Tlama I have updated the question and I have now the TNaharPalleteColor you can see.

Comment: @Arioch'The Thank on correct me. I have tested as you pointed me and updated the question.  Yes, it is from that misterious uniGUI library. The UniPanel is a descendent from TWinControl. Like all other components on that library. Everything is working fine with this library, however I decided to implement my own components version just in case that library support is gone and I need to go by myself.

Comment: you may try to make a virtual property instead https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/borland.public.delphi.vcl.components.writing/iCM8ilq5fjI

Comment: Perhaps you'd jsut to debug the saving of the component to the DFM stream and see if the property is visible to VCL and if it is in what condition it is decided to skip it. In project options set "use debug DCUs", then create the component in runtime, change the color and start saving it into TMemoryStream and go through the VCL internals to see what is actually happening. http://blocko.blogspot.ru/2005/02/delphi-stream-your-objects.html

Comment: just a blind shot - try to rename 'setcolor' method so it would not have the same name as standard ones. And doesn't that method declaratio ngenerate warnings when building your component ?

Comment: also check if in runtime you can get strings with names for all coolors values. http://www.danielmagin.de/blog/index.php/2012/11/enumeration-to-string-delphi/

Comment: @Arioch'The I have removed the FThemeController from the class above and ThemeControler now shows up on the DFM, everything working back again. My question WHY? That FThemeController is the reference to the class that holds the themes with colors. Why is that blocking? How can workaround that?

Comment: Probably you just rebuilt the sources rather than using old broken binary. Dunno. i told you above - debug the process ofsavign and see what is happening behind the hood. No one can see your program but you and if we could just guess it - we'd already had.

Comment: @Arioch'The Well, thank you for all you effort. However I am not sure it was only rebuild, because it is the first thing I try when things are not right. But what you said of debugging the save process helped me. Right now I just moved that FThemeController that was "blocking" the save to a protected section of the class and solved the problem. Why? I dont know...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the documentation for [Default Property Values](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Default_Property_Values). The default value is not saved to the .dfm.
I guess you forgot to initialize your `FThemeColor` to the default value in the constructor. (Since instance fields are always initialized to zero values, this is only necessary if the default value is non-zero.)

Comment: Thank you to point that, I have changed my constructor to initialize the FThemeColor with the same value that I have on the Default option of my property. That fixed one part of the problem. The main problem persist that is not storing the property on the DFM.

Comment: What part of the problem did it solve? As far as I know, your question only states one problem: the default value ncpWhite is not stored to the .dfm. That's by design: the default value is never stored in the .dfm. It's up to the constructor to initialize to that value (if it's non-zero). By the way, you need to rebuild the package.

Comment: Nothing was getting stored. When I open the dfm the value is not there (FThemecolor). However it is working for the panel descendent, and they use the same code. I cant see where is different. Opening another form I could see that previously even the code that in the question worked, but after saving the DFM the themecolor is removed. Your answer correct one thing that was wrong: i was expecting that the default in property initialized the variable and I was wrong. I corrected that on the constructor. However still not getting saved on the DFM

Comment: "still not getting saved on the DFM" - if the program does not work, than it is good idea to debug it. If the component's savind to stream fails, it is good idea to just trace it line by line and see where it goes off the rails.